# Twitter bootstrap + jquery-ui-datepicker on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, jquery-ui-datepicker, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any known method to have a date input working while using Twitter Bootstrap? datepicker currently looks like a mess and it doesn't look like there is an acceptable alternative in their documentation. Is there any way to either make the datepicker play nice with bootstrap or is there an alternative date/time selection UI that works with bootstrap?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check this out

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/143355/datepicker/datepicker.html

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/614

Stackoverflow forces me to insert some other lines here. It wants the body to contain 30 characters.

Answer (score 7):

The best Bootstrap Twitter datepicker is here: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker and there is a Rails gem for it: https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-datepicker-rails